# WPF Image stretch to fill doesn't stretch to the bounds of it's parents

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

Here's my XAML and how it looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="GameLenseWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="350" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="350">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="Image/topBarBg.png" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Platform" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Georgia"
                       FontSize="15" 
                       Margin="10"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPlatform" 
                      Margin="10"
                      FontFamily="Georgia"
                      FontSize="15"
                      MinHeight="30"
                      MinWidth="140"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="cmbPlatform_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem>All Platforms</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Playstation 3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>XBox 360</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Wii</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>PSP</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>DS</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="imgAbout" Grid.Row="0" Source="Image/about.png" 
               Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0 0 10 0"    />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstGames" Background="#343434" Padding="5"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <!-- SelectedItem with focus -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                       Color="Transparent" />
                        <!-- SelectedItem without focus -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                       Color="Transparent" />
                        <!-- SelectedItem text foreground -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                       Color="Black" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="120" Margin="0 10" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />                            
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="4" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                            <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                <Image Source="Image/youtube.png" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0" Height="20" Width="20" />
                            </Canvas>                           
                        </Border>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="12 0 0 0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Title:" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Release Date:" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Synopsis" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBox Background="#454545" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Synopsis}" MaxHeight="73" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

I just want to games image to stretch to fill the canvas bounds, which is inside of the rounder border.

Why is it not doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you have the images within a canvas. Basically, any time you put an element in a Canvas panel, you are disregarding the entire layout system. Elements within a canvas do not participate in layout at all. What you want to do is replace the Canvas element with a plain Grid element (you don't need to define rows or columns, it will default to a single row/column.)

**EDIT**

And actually looking more closely at what you are trying to do, you'll need to make some slight tweaks. Try this.

```
<Border BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="4">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <Image Source="Image/youtube.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </Grid>                           
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that Canvas did that! :) Thanks a bunch this solved it nicely.

Comment: Also note that I removed a couple attributes that weren't doing anything. In particular, Panel.ZIndex isn't necessary (but I suspect it was added while trying to debug this) and Grid.Row/Grid.Column which were set on the Canvas have no effect because Canvas wasn't directly inside a Grid. Glad it helped.

Answer (score -3):

your problem is here

```
<Border BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="4" Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="80" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Source="Image/youtube.png" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </Canvas>                           
</Border>
```

you have a `BorderThickness` Attribute which puts the black border around the image, just remove it or set it to `0` and this will solve the problem.

so your code will be

```
<Border BorderBrush="#202020" CornerRadius="4" Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="80" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Source="Image/youtube.png" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </Canvas>                           
</Border>
```

or

```
<Border BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4" Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="80" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Source="Image/youtube.png" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Right="0" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </Canvas>                           
</Border>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with my problem. I don't have issue with the border. I want the image to be **contained** within the border, but it doesn't. It seems to ignore the size of the canvas.

Comment: Grid.Row=0 should be in the Border element.