# Stretch Image inside Canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to have Image inside of Canvas and fit it to the window. When canvas is empty it works fine (canvas is resized within the window), however when I add Image into it, canvas is not fitting to window anymore even though I have Stretch="Uniform" applied to the Image. I illustrate this behavior below. Using the canvas is requirement unfortunately because I draw shapes over it. Any ideas please?

**Good**

```
<Window x:Class="ImageCropper.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Canvas Background="Blue">
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image]

**Bad**

```
<Window x:Class="ImageCropper.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Canvas Background="Blue">
            <Image Source="asd.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Your image is larger than area, swap Canvas for ViewBox or since it looks like it's just being used as a background anyway why not just use it as Border.Background with an ImageBrush?

Comment: I tried wrapping image with ViewBox but it doesn't help and Border is just for illustration in this question, I don't use it normally. Image unfortunately is not just background.

Comment: So you ditched the canvas for viewbox and set viewbox [stretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to uniform or uniform to fill? That should work just fine, guess we might need a more real example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: no I just wrapped Image with ViewBox. I can't ditch the canvas as I wrote in question - it is a canvas called SelectionCanvas and it draws rectangle when user moves the mouse - just a selection tool (but there is no code about positioning or sizing in that class, so it is not related) :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think stretch works with canvas very well.  See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010270/93233

However I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
    <Canvas Background="Blue" Name="canvas1">
        <Image Source="asd.png" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas1}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Comment: Great, many post states that this is not possible. Excellent!